# Replicate tables from Oracle to Postgresql using kafka not working

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka

I am using two property files one for the source and one for the sink.
I can see both the topic and the consumer created without any problems, not seeing any ERRORs in any log file or the command prompt when I run the connectors decribed above.
Still no tables are created in the destination Postgresql DB.

Trying to replicate tables from Oracle to Postgresql using kafka no confluent installation only the connector jar file.
versions:

```
kafka_2.12-2.3.0-test
confluent kafka-connect-jdbc-5.2.3.jar
ojdbc7.jar
postgresql-42.2.8.jar
```

**run the following command after starting zookeeper and kafka**

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-oracle-jdbc-source.properties config/connect-postgresql-jdbc-sink-one-table.properties
```

**source connector**

```
name=test-oracle-jdbc
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxx
connection.user=my_user
connection.password=my_password
table.whitelist=LOADER_JOBS
tables="LOADER_JOBS"
mode=timestamp
timestamp.column.name=START_TIME
topic.prefix=test_jdbc_loader_jobs
numeric.mapping=best_fit
```

**sink connector**

```
name=test-postgres-jdbc-one-table
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
max.retries=20
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
connection.user=postgres
connection.password=postgres
topics.regex=test_jdbc_loader_jobs
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in the sink connector, the property **auto.create** was misspelled
missing the starting "a" it was **uto.create**.
It works like a charm